# How memory allocation takes place in scala

Tags: java, scala, memory, memory-management, allocation

As we know that unlike java, scala has everything as object.

For example we have-

```
object A{
    val arg1=1
    def myFun(arg2:Int)=arg1
}

class A{  
    val arg1=1
    def myFun(arg2:Int)=arg1
}

trait A{
    val arg1=1
    def myFun(arg2:Int)=arg1
}
```

- Now as everything in scala is an object so how the memory allocation will take place?
- Is everything going to get memory in heap other than the reference variables ?
- And in java when the class instance is created then the methods and variables in that class gets the memory in heap. How does it happens for a Singleton Objects here?
- If everything is in Heap, will it not affect the performance?
- As in Java, Memory is divided into 5 sections i.e. Heap, Stack, MethodArea etc. What about in scala, how does the memory allocation takes place?

Comment: So your question is more or less: How does memory management work in scale?

Comment: The types are unified, but that doesn't mean "everything is an object" at runtime.

Comment: seems like there is room for optimization if a Scala class has a val assigned to a literal. You'd think the val with the literal assignment could be converted to a static final in java land since the value can never change in any class instanciation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Scala** runs on the **JVM** and it's base on the Java library.

**scala** file(*.scala) will be compiled to the java class bytecode and run these on **JVM**. for your example:

```
object A{
    val arg1=1
    def myFun(arg2:Int)=arg1
}
```

will be translated to(decompile bytecode by javap):

```
public class A$ extends java.lang.Object{
    public static final A$ MODULE$;
    private final int arg1;
    public static {};
    public int arg1();
    public int myFun(int);
    public A$();
}
```

---

```
class A{  
    val arg1=1
    def myFun(arg2:Int)=arg1
}
```

will be translated to(decompile bytecode  by javap):

```
public class A extends java.lang.Object{
    private final int arg1;
    public int arg1();
    public int myFun(int);
    public A();
}
```

---

```
trait A{
    val arg1=1
    def myFun(arg2:Int)=arg1
}
```

will be translated to(decompile bytecode  by javap):

```
public interface A{
public abstract void $line5$$read$A$_setter_$arg1_$eq(int);

public abstract int arg1();

public abstract int myFun(int);

}
```

so for your other memory questions, I think it's same as **Java**.

Comment: Thanx @chengpohi, I accept your answer. But can you please clarify that what this line means :  **"public static final A$ MODULE$;"** 
and also why the val arg1=1 is being converted to  _private final int arg1;_ and  _public int arg1();_
I mean I understand the conversion to private final int agr1;
but am not clear with public int arg1().